# Passing Datetime from JSON to WCF POST

Tags: c#, json, wcf, datetime

i have a class like this:

```
public class BudgetTransactionRequest
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string transaction_code { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public double? amount { get; set; }



        public DateTime request_date { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "request_date")]
        public string req_date { get; set; }

        [OnSerializing]
        void OnSerializing(StreamingContext context)
        {
            this.req_date = this.request_date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        [OnDeserialized]
        void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
        {
            DateTime value;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(this.req_date, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out value))
            {
                this.request_date = value;
            }
        }
}
```

Using fiddler, i tried to call this web service by sending JSON  like below:

```
{"transaction_code":"MCN34", "amount":2000.000,"request_date":"/Date(1235764800000)/"}
```

But i got this following error:

```
{"ErrorDetails":"DateTime is less than minumum value supported by CrmDateTime. Actual value: 01\/01\/0001 00:00:00, Minimum value supported: 01\/01\/1753 00:00:00\"}
```

What am i missing here ?

Comment: I think your problem is that you have declare a `public` variable called `request_date`, so the binder tries to set both properties: `request_date` and `req_date` (due the `DataMember(Name = "request_date")]`. For teasting purpose, just change `public DateTime request_date { get; set; }` to `public DateTime request_date_test { get; set; }` It should work properly.

Comment: @Rumpelstinsk: Unfortunately, its not working. Any other idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i implemented a method with your class and its works just fine.
here is my method:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "*", UriTemplate = @"/BudgetTransaction")]
[Description("use this method to add an Employee Account")]
BudgetTransactionRequest BudgetTransaction(BudgetTransactionRequest ws);
```

my request with Fiddler:

```
POST localhost/BudgetTransaction HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Length: 86
Content-Type: application/json

{"transaction_code":"MCN34", "amount":2000.000,"request_date":"/Date(1235764800000)/"}
```

response:

```
{"amount":2000,"req_date":"02\/27\/2009 8:00 PM","request_date":"\/Date(1235764800000)\/","transaction_code":"MCN34"}
```

Comment: Hi, i found the problem is the variable name. Just like the rumpel says. I change the name of Datetime Request_date. And place [Datamember] above it. Instead above string req_date

Answer (score 0):

Your code is slightly wrong.
You declared req_date as
 `[DataMember(Name = "request_date")]
        public string req_date { get; set; }`

If you send request_date as "request_date":"/Date(1235764800000)/" means, the date value will stored in req_date variable.
Then, you try to assign request_date to req_date. By default, Null value in request_date  variable.
If you pass NULL value means, it will take default value as ' 01/01/0001 00:00:00'.